# Button only allows clicking once

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have a contact form overlay on the webpage, I have got this completed, however, when I click the button I must refresh the screen to allow it to be clicked again, how can I click the button multiple times if I cancel the window and want back into the form?

Edit: I have added the HTML portion in, the rest is PHP mail and CSS code which is all correct as of now. I have looked at the suggestion of preventDefault(), however, I am unable to get it to work, all I get is no result and just denies me access to my popup.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contact-icon").click(function () {
        $("#contact-popup").show();
    });
    //Contact Form validation on click event
    $("#contact-form").on("submit", function () {
        var valid = true;
        $(".info").html("");
        $("inputBox").removeClass("input-error");

        var userName = $("#userName").val();
        var userEmail = $("#userEmail").val();
        var subject = $("#subject").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();

        if (userName == "") {
            $("#userName-info").html("required.");
            $("#userName").addClass("input-error");
        }
        if (userEmail == "") {
            $("#userEmail-info").html("required.");
            $("#userEmail").addClass("input-error");
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!userEmail.match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/))
        {
            $("#userEmail-info").html("invalid.");
            $("#userEmail").addClass("input-error");
            valid = false;
        }

        if (subject == "") {
            $("#subject-info").html("required.");
            $("#subject").addClass("input-error");
            valid = false;
        }
        if (message == "") {
            $("#userMessage-info").html("required.");
            $("#message").addClass("input-error");
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;

    });
});
</script>
```

```
<li><div id="contact-icon">
        <button id="buttoncontact"> Contact Me </button>
    </div></li>
<!--Contact Form-->
    <div id="contact-popup">
        <form class="contact-form" action="" id="contact-form"
            method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>
            <button id="closecontact">Close</button> </span>
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>Name: </label><span id="userName-info"
                        class="info"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"
                        class="inputBox" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>Email: </label><span id="userEmail-info"
                        class="info"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="userEmail" name="userEmail"
                        class="inputBox" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>Subject: </label><span id="subject-info"
                        class="info"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject"
                        class="inputBox" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>Message: </label><span id="userMessage-info"
                        class="info"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message"
                        class="inputBox"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Google for preventDefault()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide more information about your code....what works and what doesnt.
Do you get any errors in console. Print screen....jsfiddle example or something.

At the moment my guess is that your event handler is assigned to the button at the time of "page ready" event. When you open the popup...it re-renders html and removes your button temporarily. If you cancel your popup...your button is re-added to the page...but without event listener.

You can try replacing

```
$("#contact-icon").click(function () {
    // Also, add console.log("contact icon clicked"); so u know the listener triggered.
    $("#contact-popup").show();
});
// with
$("#contact-icon").on("click", function () {
    $("#contact-popup").show();
});
// and see if it makes a difference.

I think your problem is that you remove the element when you close the popup. When you remove it...its gone. Instead of removing it...hide it.
```

Check the example below
https://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/fgsc54dk/4/

Comment: I updated my question with the HTML for you.  I'm sorry about that, I am so new to this world.

Comment: Where is the `contact-icon` element being removed from the page? I don't see that anywhere in his code. Conjecture maybe? Also, the `.live()` method was deprecated in favor of `.on()` back in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: @cssyphus the span element with id='close' removes an element from the page. It wont come back unless you refresh the page.

Comment: Rainer, you are absolutely correct - I didn't notice the `onClick` code. Your answer is therefore correct, as soon as you change from `.live()` to `.on()` +1